# C++ 17 Metaprogramming recursive struct: enum or constexpr

Tags: c++, templates, enums, c++17, constexpr

For illustrative purposes, I'm showing two small, slightly different templated recursive definitions. One uses an `enum` and the other uses `static constexpr` to define a value.

I have inspected the output assembly from both programs, and they are exactly the same, and semantically they also appear the same.

I think `constexpr` is maybe a bit more modern, but are there any differences between using `enum`/`static constexpr`, or are there any particular use cases where the difference would really matter?

```cpp
// using enum
template<uint64_t N>
struct Sum {
    enum : uint64_t { value = N + Sum<N - 1>::value };
};

template<>
struct Sum<0> {
    enum : uint64_t { value = 1 };
};
```

```cpp
// using static constexpr
template<uint64_t N>
struct Sum {
    static constexpr uint64_t value = N + Sum<N - 1>::value;
};

template<>
struct Sum<0> {
    static constexpr uint64_t value = 1;
};
```

Extracting value:

```cpp
#define sum(n) (Sum<n>::value)
```

Comment: its a bit unclear what you are asking. You write "they are exactly the same" and then ask where that difference matters

Comment: What I meant: The C++-programs differ, but in this particular case they generate the same assembly output. So I was wondering how they are /should be /can be used differently, and what I should keep in mind as I'm learning more.

Comment: Ok, understand. `value`  is of different type in the two examples, that might be relevant.

Comment: Off the top, `&Sum<0>::value` would compile with second example, but fail with the first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most significant difference (since C++17 avoids the need for an out-of-class definition for the static data member) is that enumerators are instantiated **along** with the containing class, whereas static data members are instantiated only when **needed**.  (Note, however, that MSVC, at least, doesn’t always properly defer them.)

This matters when you have several such constants and some of them make sense only for certain specializations.  **Errors** in an initializer like `T::maybe_exists` will not be triggered by instantiating the class in the static data member case.

Answer (score 1):

another difference: about [***ODR-used***](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition).

as @Igor Tandetnik said, when you use `&Sum<0>::value`, it will only work if `value` is a `static constexpr` variable. that's because, `value` is a literal for an enumerator, instead of a variable. but pay attention, `&value` is an **ODR-used**, which demands `value` has **one and only one** definition somewhere. so you have to declare `uint64_t const Sum<0>::value;` at `XXX.cpp` to provide the definition, before C++17 (`static constexpr` variable is implicitly an `inline` variable after C++17, and an `inline` variable is allowed to have more than one definitions among translation units).

maybe you think "I won't use `&value` at all". but you will be in trouble at another case: `uint64_t const& a = value`, which is also **ODR-used**. for an enumerator, its lifetime will be extended by the reference (as [reference initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization)). but `static constexpr` variable will not and demands the definition, just like using `&value`. it always cause some trouble when you use some function passing by reference, such as `std::find`.